# How to import data into database without using importcsv extension

Tags: php, codeigniter, yii

I have one problem in importing data into database.
I want to ask that how to import data into database without using importcsv extension in yii framework?
Because that extension is not usefull........

Comment: What database? What format of data?

Comment: Mysql database and the file type is CSV. We can read file using PHPExcel and for insert dat data into table we have to write insert query. We can use load data infile syntax but in dis case Can we validate CSV data means the empty cell or datatypes?

Comment: what do you mean by "this extension is not useful" ? The extension does what it's says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I load data from csv in migrations this way:

```
public function safeUp()
{
    $handle = fopen('/path/to/csv.csv', "r");
    if (false !== $handle) {
        fgetcsv($handle, 1000); // Skip header row
        while (false !== ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000))) {
            $this->insert('table_name', array(
                'column1' => $row[0], 
                'column2' => $row[1],
            ));
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx orreply.... but u have any idea that can we add data using any loop, means can we connect excel file and insert data into table as it is without using any loop?

Comment: No, I don't know any application, extension or component that would do that.

Comment: using COM class we can do that but problem is COM class is not working in linux :(.

Comment: I got solution we can do it using PHPExcel class. :)